# Selenium script behaves differently in AWS Batch environment compared to local Windows PC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-batch

I have developed a Selenium script using Python that interacts with a website. The script runs successfully on my local Windows PC. However, when I try to run the same script in an AWS Batch environment with identical configurations, the script behaves differently. It seems like some components are getting changed in the AWS Batch environment.

Details:

I'm using Selenium with Python to automate interactions with a website.
The script runs successfully on my local Windows PC.
I have set up an AWS Batch environment with the same configurations as my local PC.
When I run the script in the AWS Batch environment, I encounter unexpected behavior.
I have checked the versions of Python, Selenium, and other relevant dependencies in both environments, and they match.
I have also verified that the browser versions and configurations are consistent between the environments.
The AWS Batch environment is set up to execute the script in headless mode, similar to my local PC.
Despite these efforts, the script still behaves differently in the AWS Batch environment.
Specific issues observed in the AWS Batch environment:

I am facing this issue with the calender date picker element.

Code snippet:

```
# create a new Chrome session
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--incognito')
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

# Navigate to the application home page
url = "https://www.websiteurl.com/sessions/new"
driver.get(url)
```

Any suggestions on what could be causing this discrepancy and how to troubleshoot it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When moving a Selenium script from a local PC to AWS Batch, environmental differences can cause unexpected behavior. While your versions match, AWS Batch's virtualized environment might handle browser interactions differently, particularly in headless mode. Ensure your script accommodates potential timing issues or differences in page load times. Also, consider differences in network speed and availability in AWS. Debugging with detailed logs and screenshots can help identify where the behavior diverges. Sometimes, tweaking timeouts or waiting strategies fixes these issues.